# python - np.random.random round up to 1 decimal

Tags: python, random, numbers

Trying to generate numbers using `np.random.random`:

```
for portfolio in range(2437):
    weights = np.random.random(3)
    weights /= np.sum(weights)

    print(weights)
```

It works just as expected:

```
[0.348674 0.329747 0.321579]
[0.215606 0.074008 0.710386]
[0.350316 0.589782 0.059901]
[0.639651 0.025353 0.334996]
[0.697505 0.171061 0.131434]
.
.
.
.
```

however, how do i change the numbers such that each row is is limited to 1 decimal, like:

```
[0.1 0.2 0.7]
[0.2 0.2 0.6]
[0.5 0.4 0.1]
.
.
.
.
```

Comment: Note, if you really want to round them and use them later rounded, you'll greatly change the distribution of numbers. F.e., you'll get `0.0` for all numbers in the bin [0.0...0.05), with bin width 0.05. But `0.1` will be twice as probable because it will be returned for all numbers in the bin [0.05...0.15), with the bin width of 0.1. `1.0` will suffer the same fate, half the probability of 0.9, 0.8, etc

Answer (score 5):

You can use

```py
In [1]: weights.round(1)
Out[2]: array([0.4, 0.5, 0.2])
```

The argument to `round` is the amount of decimal digits you want. It also accepts negative arguments, meaning rounding to a larger-than-1 power of ten:

```py
In [2]: np.array([123, 321, 332]).round(-1)
Out[2]: array([120, 320, 330])
```

Answer (score 3):

For visualization only, you can use `np.set_printoptions`:

```
import numpy as np
np.set_printoptions(precision=1, suppress=True)

np.random.rand(4, 4)
```

```
array([[0.8, 0.8, 0.3, 0.3],
       [0.1, 0.2, 0. , 0.2],
       [0.8, 0.2, 1. , 0.2],
       [0.2, 0.7, 0.6, 0.2]])
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try `np.round`:

```
weights  = np.round(weights, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe my answer is not the most efficient but there is it:

```
for portfolio in range(2437):
    weights = np.random.random(3)
    weights /= np.sum(weights)
    t_weights = []
    for num in weights:
        num *= 10
        num = int(num)
        num = float(num) / 10
        t_weights.append(num)
    weights = t_weights

    print(weights)
```